# RemoteDesktop Connection with MSTSCLib c# windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, rdp

Im currentyl trying to connect to a RDP-Server with the following lines of code:

```
this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.Server = ((Computer)this.extendedTreeView1.SelectedNode).ipAdressen[0].ToString();
this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.UserName = username;
IMsTscNonScriptable secured = (IMsTscNonScriptable)this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.GetOcx();
secured.ClearTextPassword = password;
this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.Connect();
```

But the control remains empty - no errors, no stacktraces :(
Im trying to connect to a Windows 8.1 machine - same OS on the connecting side.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Connect() runs asynchronously.  You *must* subscribe the events to discover what's going on.  Never skip OnLogonError and OnFatalError.

Comment: I subscribed to some events:
this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.OnDisconnected += axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1_OnDisconnected;
                this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.OnLogonError += axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1_OnLogonError;
                this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.OnFatalError += axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1_OnFatalError;
                this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.OnConnecting += axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1_OnConnecting;
                this.axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1.OnConnected += axMsTscAxNotSafeForScripting1_OnConnected;

but not one gets fired :(

Comment: Are you running a message loop in your app? Are you running in the STA model?